# How to access session object in socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io, express-session

I'm using express-session, and I set the session object on a login page.  That all works fine.  My socket.io connections aren't initiated and used until further into the site. Reading the socket.io documentation it mentions that you can access the `request` object that initiated the socket connection. This doesn't seem to be same as the express-session object viz:

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.request.session)
});
```

outputs `undefined`.  There is a `request` object viz: `console.log(socket.request)` outputs `[object Object]`.

Is there a way to access the express-session session object (that was set on a previous page before the socket connection was made) through a socket.io connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) , the reference has information of how to share session from express-session.

Comment: That's perfect!  Cheers.